# Scala macro that returns an empty AST

Tags: scala, macros

I've created a simple macro that generates compiler warnings (or errors) if the current date is passed the FIXME (or TODO) date specified.

The macro implementation ([see here](https://github.com/tysonjh/fixme/blob/master/macros/src/main/scala/FIXME.scala)) for Scala 2.10.4 used `c.Expr[Any]` return type, in 2.11.0 it is a whitebox macro that returns `c.Tree`.

In either case returning `c.Expr[Any](EmptyTree)` or `EmptyTree` respectively returns a value. Supposing the following invocation of the macro,

```
def hi() {
  FIXME("2073/04/10: This will abort compilation if not fixed by 2073/04/10")
  println("hi")
}
```

Compilation generates the following,

```
def hi(): Unit = {
  (<empty>: scala.runtime.BoxedUnit);
  scala.this.Predef.println("hi")
};
```

at the macro call site. Is it possible to generate the following instead:

```
def hi(): Unit = {
  scala.this.Predef.println("hi")
};
```

Comment: "method literalUnit in trait ExprUtils is deprecated: Use quasiquotes instead"... but also it generates `(scala.runtime.BoxedUnit.UNIT: scala.runtime.BoxedUnit);`

Comment: Then what do you mean by "nothing"? Literal `()` value seems to be the right way to express "no code". In Scala 2.11 you can do this with a quasiquote `q"()"`, AFAIK.

Comment: Updated to be more clear. You are correct regarding q"()", however it still produces the `BoxedUnit`.

Comment: @ghik your suggestion q"()" actually worked too, if I change to a `whitebox` and define the macro `def apply(format: String): Any = macro fixmeMacro.impl`, with the impl as `def impl(c: Context)(format: c.Expr[String]): c.Expr[Any] = ...` the code generated is `();` which is awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider making the fixable block an argument to the macro:

```
def hi = FIXME("...") {  println(...) }
```

Compare what the compiler does with elidable code: it elides to a "zero" value, not an empty tree.

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.10.x/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/transform/UnCurry.scala#L515

You might also consider a macro annotation.

Comment: An annotation is on the list of features to add. Unfortunately only having annotations would limit where the invocations could happen (ie. at class/method definitions). The solution you propose is interesting but diverges from the goal of mimicking the //TODO and //FIXME comments often seen in code.

Comment: @tysonjh How would you handle `val x = FIXME("2010/01/01: hi")`? It might make more sense to declare the result as `Unit`.

Comment: never thought of that. I suppose I would do the same as the elidable annotation and mkZero for the RHS/body. I've been following through the code you linked and feel like I'm getting close by generating a `Literal(Constant(null))` as done [here](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/reflect/scala/reflect/internal/TreeGen.scala#L260). Just dealing with a different compiler generated warning "warning: a pure expression does nothing in statement position you may be omitting necessary parentheses"

Comment: I'd just like to note that the elideable annotation will also replace the entire tree, not just the RHS. Thank you for pointing to the standard library, great reference.